# Success function in my ajax request not executing

Tags: php, ajax, function

**First problem:** Page would redirect, but my AJAX request was ignored.

**New problem:** AJAX request posts the data, but page will not redirect.

My goal is to send the AJAX request, confirm that the data have been sent and stored on the server, and then redirect to a new page once that has completed.

I have tried using a success function within my AJAX request to achieve this. If I put the page redirect OUTSIDE the AJAX request, it redirects the page but the AJAX response is halted. If I put the page redirect INSIDE the AJAX request, the data post but the page does not redirect.

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "saveData.php",
        dataType: "text/plain",
        ContentType: "charset=utf-8",
        data: {"data": surveydata, "userID": userID, "trialType": trialType},
        success: function (data) {
            if (!data.error) {
                console.log("success");
                window.location.replace("anotherpage.html");
            } else {
                console.log("error");
        }}})
```

I have also tried it this way:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "saveData.php",
        dataType: "text/plain",
        ContentType: "charset=utf-8",
        data: {"data": surveydata, "userID": userID, "trialType": trialType},
        success: function (data) {
                console.log("success");
                window.location.replace("anotherpage.html");
        }}})
```

I want to achieve both a successful page redirect and the posting of the data. I am unaware of how to force the page redirect to wait until the AJAX request has succeeded. I have read through the other questions on this topic and tried several methods, but none have worked so far.

Comment: What does this have to do with PHP?

Comment: in the second version you have one `}` too much (left over from the `else {`)

Comment: whats the response from other side ? how do you assure that it has posted the data without errors ? can you show us  console.log(data) from success

Comment: did you try an error callback? Maybe the server doesn't respond with the correct headers

Comment: Fixed the extra bracket. Same problem: Data posts but no page redirect.

I am sure it posts the correct data because it creates a new text file that has a line of information on it and that information is accurate.

I am not sure what you mean by an error callback, but I am willing to try anything.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my own problem. I could never get an acknowledgement of a successful AJAX request, even though the data posted just fine. So I developed a workaround: If the data POST just fine, then all I need to do is redirect the page after a delay (to give the data time to post).

So I have my submit button execute two functions:

```
onclick="saveData(); redirect()"
```

Then, the AJAX request goes normally:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "saveData.php",
        dataType: "text/plain",
        ContentType: "charset=utf-8",
        data: {"data": surveydata, "userID": userID, "trialType": trialType},
        })
```

And at the same time, I start a timer to redirect the page:

```
    function redirect(){
            document.getElementById("submitBtn").disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("submitBtn").value = "Redirecting...";
            setTimeout(function(){ window.location.replace("anotherpage.html"); }, 3000);
        }
```

This makes it so that after 3 seconds, the page redirects, giving the AJAX function time to post the data first. It is not a perfect solution because the server could hang and the data could be lost, but so far my tests show that it is enough time. If I really wanted to be cautious, I could increase this time but I don't feel it necessary.

I would also like to say that I appreciated the comments that were intended to help. I think many times if a question is similar on SO, people ignore it because "clearly this has been answered before". But none of those solutions worked for me, and I think my problem was unique.

Answer (score -1):

There is an extra `}` in the end and that causes the problem & Why are you going the far way ? just try this code above for POST request :

```
$.post("saveData.php",
  {
    "data": surveydata,
    "userID": userID,
    "trialType": trialType
  },
  function(data, status){

  if (status === 'success') {
      console.log("success");
      window.location.replace("anotherpage.html");
  }

});
```

Comment: Same result when trying this code - posts the data but no page redirect.

Comment: does console log success ? if yes , then there is problem with your window.location.replace , also try using a URL instead of anotherpage.html , e.g https://google.com

Comment: so there is a problem with your post request and it does not succeeds , is there any error in console ?

Comment: Well the data post without any errors; it is only the redirect that fails..

Comment: how can you be sure that data posts ? maybe you have a unbreaking loop or ... that continues execution and timeouts the connection ... check if you could post this data to your page with <form> using POST method manually

Comment: I will try a manual post. That might just be what I am forced to do anyways. I say that the data POST fine because I can see an XMR post request in the console that says "OK" status 200. Also, in saveData.php I tell it to create a new file with some information from the page and that goes just fine.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure your php program is returning data to the ajax request.